# How to connect Kafka consumer with SSL setup with any of Node JS modules

Tags: node.js, ssl, kafka-consumer-api

I want to connect external kafka topic provided by vendor; as we are already developed service on top of Node JS.

So I am looking for

> NodeJS kafka consumer and with SSL setup;

as the kafka-server needs the details while handshake;

This what I tried with `kafkajs` module already

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Kafka = require('kafkajs').Kafka;
var logLevel = require('kafkajs').logLevel;


var _kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId: 'my-app',
    brokers: ['broker:9093'],
    logLevel: logLevel.DEBUG,
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        ca: [fs.readFileSync('./cert/ca.trust.certificate.pem', 'utf-8')],
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/client-cert-signed.pem', 'utf-8'),
    }
});


try {
    const consumer = _kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'test-group' }, { maxWaitTimeInMs: 3000 });

    consumer.connect();
    consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'external-topic', fromBeginning: true });

    consumer.run({
        eachMessage: async({ topic, partition, message }) => {
            console.log({
                partition: 2,
                offset: message.offset,
                value: message.value.toString(),
            })
        },
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error while connect : ' + err);
}
```

It is giving

> Connection error: 101057795:error:1408E0F4:SSL routines:ssl3_get_message:unexpected message:openssl\ssl\s3_both.c:408:\
>    while connecting;

Could you please help me with resolution or suggest me any npm module, so that I can give a try examples are so welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add `key` attribute in `ssl` Options; as this one is the mandatory while handshake;